# Error in accessing json object

Tags: json

I am trying to access a JSON object I get as a response. It looks like

```
{
   "lob": "LH",
   "policyNumber": 12345,
   "agentCode": "1910987",
   "totalAmount": 181.75,
   "dueAmount": 181.75,
   "dueDate": "2013-10-03",
   "status":
   {
       "code": "5",
       "description": "under",
       "date": "2013-11-15"
   },
   "payment-method":
   {
       "code": "00",
       "description": "ΜΕΤΡΗΤΑ"
   }
}
```

I am trying `WebResponse.payment-method.code == '00'`
which gives me an error `"ReferenceError: method is not defined".` 
The thing is that I was able to check all previous object properties like this and it worked well. `WebResponse.status.code` works fine. Is there any chance the  '-' in payment-method may be causing the problem? Can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the hyphen is conflicting with JS syntax, so you'll nee to use square-bracket notation with a string:

```
WebResponse['payment-method'].code == '00'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate response! You are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the brace syntax `WebResponse['payment-method'].code`